# Search a SubVector within Another Vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a std::vector (haystack) within which I want to look up another std::vector. Is there an STL algorithm that does it already or I have to code one of the string matching algorithms.

The haystack vector has the contents of a (sometimes) binary file and I want to look up some strings of interest in it. Converting to std::string may or may not be an option as the haystack vector may have binary data.

Comment: How about `std::search`?

Comment: Does it have to be in order, or something like if every element in the smaller vector exists in the larger?

Comment: Looks like std::search it is. Thanks